# Cannot change movement number or name of a classical piece in iTunes

Tags: itunes, metadata

I just imported a classical CD into iTunes, and am trying to correct the information from Gracenote.  But when I select "use work and movement" it will only let me enter the work name.  "Movement **_ of _** named ______" fields are all blank and will not accept focus or typing.

This seems to be a bug in 12.7.1.14—it apparently [worked as expected](https://www.macworld.com/article/3121662/software-entertainment/how-to-better-organize-classical-music-in-itunes.html) in 12.5.  **But maybe it's something I can fix?** (instead of submit a report and get a stream of excuses from Apple).

Amadeus and exiftool will allow me to set tags without iTunes running, and iTunes will show the changes when launched.  Are there specific tags for these three fields that I can set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered that I can edit those fields in my library, but not in the import window.  And I can't get access to the file from the import window to change tags.  That is, “show in finder” is not on the context menu in that window.

Thus, I can make them correct in my library, but I can't send the corrections to Gracenote.

While fiddling with this I also discovered that if I select a track in the import window and change tags, the changes do not “stick” if the import of that track has already completed.  For example, select all of them and fix a typo in the album name: I end up with two albums, one with the wrong name and the first few tracks, and my correction on the other tracks.

Comment: Accepting my own answer since no other is offered.